# How to compute precision and recall for a system that generates questions?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, information-retrieval, nlp-question-answering

My system generates questions from a set of sentences. Can generate multiple questions for a single sentence depending on the quality of the sentence. Humans are also given the same set of sentences to generate questions.

For example:

sentence: The capital of Russia is Moscow.

============# System-Generated Questions #=============

Question 1: What the capital of Russia is?

Question 2: What is Moscow?

============# Human-Generated Questions #=============

Question 1: What is the capital of Russia?

Question 2: What is Moscow?

Question 3: Is the capital of Russia Moscow?

I want to evaluate the precision, recall and accuracy of my system. But I do not know how to compute such measures for the Question generation system case.

Data

1. Annotated set of system-generated questions (Acceptable, Unacceptable)
2. Human-generated questions (for the same set of sentences)

Given this data, How do I compute these measures?

Comment: Does annotated set of system-generated questions include _all_ possible questions?

Comment: The system generates questions for specific WH-words. It follows the following strategy: Find _answers_ in the sentences, then generate _question_ for each _answer_.

Comment: Can you assume the human-generated questions contain *all* possible questions for that sentence?

Comment: Yes I can assume that Human-generated questions are _all_ possible questions.

Comment: There are a lot more metrics beyond Precision/Recall/F-measure. Consider trying to compute and reporting something like the average edit distance or a graph similarity metric for parses between generated and provided questions.

Comment: Please be more specific Josep, All I want to compute Precision, recall and f-measure. If you know how I can do that it will be helpful if you provide a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think understand your situation, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

If you're trying to compute precision, recall, and accuracy (I wonder if there might be more appropriate performance metrics, but that's besides the point), we need to define what a true positive, false positive, true negative, and false negative are.

If your system is generating questions, and you have a set of ground truth questions generated by humans (we assume the humans have generated EVERY acceptable question possible for every sentence), we know that any question your system is generating is a positive (either T/F):

True Positive: Question generated by system **matches** a human-generated question for that sentence.

False Positive: Question generated by system **does not match** a human-generated question for that sentence.

True Negative: I don't think it's easy to compute, since your system only generates what it thinks are questions. I think it would be every single unacceptable question your system did not generate, that is also not found in the human-generated questions.

False Negative: A human-generated question that was not generated by your system.

It's then straightforward to plug these into the equations for computing precision and recall:

Precision = TP / TP + FP

Recall = TP / TP + FN

Because it's not easy to think about TN, I don't think it's reasonable to compute the accuracy. You could instead compute the false discovery rate (1 - precision).

Comment: If a question is annotated as **Unacceptable**, it is because during the annotation of _system-generated_ questions the annotator found deficiencies in the question (such as _ungrammatical_, _vagueness_, _does_ _not_ _make_ _sense_, _etc_...). Otherwise the annotator marks as **Acceptable** if there's no deficiency (meaning that the question generated by the system is correct).

Comment: I am a bit skeptical about the **Unacceptable** scenario.

Comment: Ah okay, I misinterpreted something. I'll update my answer.